# Unable to fetch correct data using join subquery in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

```
$serviceId = Service::select('id')->where('provider_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('is_deleted', 0);
$list = DB::table('service_galleries')
            ->where('is_deleted', 0)
            ->joinSub($serviceId, 'sid', function ($qry) {
                $qry->on('service_galleries.service_id', '=', 'sid.id');
            })->get();
```

From the above code I need `id` of every row in service galleries table but is return service_id in the field of id, which means service_id and id is same

Comment: Try the [`leftJoinSub`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#subquery-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Laravel's Eloquent built in [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) ? This could save you a lot of headaches.

For example in your Service model you can create a function for example:

```
public function galleries(){
    $this->hasMany(ServiceGalleries::class);
}
```

And in your ServiceGalleries model (don't know the actual name)

```
public function service(){
    $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
}
```

Comment: for performance time. ex: laravel do `where exists`  when is slower than a `join`.